# Reload UITableView after removing Subview

Tags: iphone

I have added `TableView` which data will be dynamically changes after filling form. and I have inserted form on `TableView` view controller class. But can't able to reload the tableview.

How can reload `UITableView` after removing Subview?

Please suggest solution.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use - `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Can you show the code how you are removing the subview and calling reloadData?

Comment: [_appDelegate._sessionInfoViewController._tableView reloadData]; for reloading the table which i want to reload. [self.view removeFromSuperview]; and this is for the removing the superview.. and I have inserted my subview on ViewController which is base controller of the application.

Comment: try logging NSLog(@"%@", _appDelegate._sessionInfoViewController._tableView); and check if table view instance is present?

Comment: You need to check where you are releasing tableview, either you need to show some code or try yourself debugging it.